# How to copy uint8_t * to char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, uint8t

I'm trying to copy a uint8_t* into an char array, the uint8_t* is non terminating but I have another uint8_t with the length of the message.
How do I copy the uint8_t* into a char array without getting segfauts.

```
uint8_t *name; //Set to something beforehand, it's part of an server STUN.
uint8 name_length; //Also set to something I just know is less than 255.

//I've tried
char nameArray[255];
memcpy(nameArray, name, name_length-1);
nameArray[name_length] = '\0';
```

Segfaults due to invalid read size

Comment: This would need more information. What exactly is the value of name_length? At which point does it segfault?

Comment: *I just know is less than 255* And just how do you "know" this?  The code you have posted does not demonstrate that, and in fact will result in undefined behavior should `name_length` actually be `255`.

Comment: Just tested your code, by pointing *name to some `char[]` that is 10 long and set size to 5, and it works fine for me. So I am going to go out on a limb and say the error is not in the code that you have posted... Probably you should print the address of *name and the value of name_langth

Comment: Aside: `nameArray[name_length] = '\0';` is off by one, since you only copy `name_length-1` bytes.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `name_length`?

Comment: You should use `unsigned char`, otherwise you'll get undefined behavior if `char` defaults to `signed` and any of the values in `name` are out of range.

Comment: "invalid read size" probably means that `name_length` is wrong.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of integer promotion of the variable `name_length` at the call site of `memcpy()` is converted into `int`. If the value is 0 (zero) the subtraction of 1 results in a value of -1. This is then converted into `size_t` which gives SIZE_MAX. `memcpy()` happily starts copying that amount but runs beyond the limit of the allowed address range.

Since the subtraction of 1 is wrong in the first place, remove it.

Comment: This answer points out one of several issues with the code snippet. Someone else pointed out that char could be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. Take a look in gdb or use printf to see what is going on.

Comment: By the letters of the standard this is correct. But I never saw a system that threw a segmentation fault if a `uint8_t` value was not assignable to a `char`. At the machine level the byte (or whatever it is) is simply copied. So this is most probably no reason for the segmentation fault.